# runtime.exec() at Java ME 8 not supported. Is there an alternative?

Tags: java, java-me, runtime.exec

I have to call a shell script from a Java ME 8 Application but the [CLDC 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/api/cldc/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) doesn't implement `Runtime.exec()`. Is there any other opportunities to call an shell script with Java ME?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you might want to consider using a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

> This class is used to create operating system processes.
> Each `ProcessBuilder` instance manages a collection of process attributes. The `start()` method creates a new `Process` instance with those attributes. The `start()` method can be invoked repeatedly from the same instance to create new subprocesses with identical or related attributes.

Usage example from docs:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
```

Comment: I use Java ME with the CLDC 8 there is only a subset of the Java SE. The `ProcessBuilder` isn't implemented in the CLDC 8.